# Configure Symfony 5.3 to use a dedicated MongoDB database for testing

Tags: database, mongodb, symfony, testing, phpunit

I am new with Symfony (5.3) and I would like to make some phpunit tests on my repositories.
A MongoDB database is used through doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle (4.3).

The point is that I don't manage to send my fixtures in a test database. They're going in the default one which I use for dev.

I suppose I can configure the doctrine_mongodb.yaml but right now I didn't find a way to make it work.

I am not sure it is important but my document is mapped as follows :

```
<?php

namespace App\Document;

use App\Document\EstablishmentDateStoreDocument;
use App\Document\GroupDocument;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as ODM;
use Symfony\Component\Uid\Uuid;

/**
 * 
 * @ODM\Document(db="database_local", collection="establishment",repositoryClass=EstablishmentRepository::class)
 * 
 */
class EstablishmentDocument
{
    /**
     * @ODM\Id(type="string")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ODM\Field(type="string")
     */
    private string $uuid;

.....
```

and my doctrine_mongodb.yaml :

```
doctrine_mongodb:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
    auto_generate_hydrator_classes: true
    connections:
        default:
            server: '%env(resolve:MONGODB_URL)%'
            options: {}
    default_database: '%env(resolve:MONGODB_DB)%'
    document_managers:
        default:
            auto_mapping: true
            mappings:
                App:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: annotation
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Document'
                    prefix: 'App\Document'
                    alias: App
```

Unfortunately I haven't found many ressources on that topic (testing/Symfony/MongoDB). Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: *"I would like to make some phpunit tests on my repositories"* Meaning you do not know how or are having trouble with your current tests? What specifically are you testing? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You should use this bundle: https://github.com/liip/LiipTestFixturesBundle

Then with this configuration in you framework.yml file:

```
liip_test_fixtures:
    cache_db:
         sqlite: liip_test_fixtures.services_database_backup.sqlite
```

All you fixtures data is loaded into a local sqlite DB.